# magento atrributes values not showing on admin and frontend

Tags: database, admin, frontend, magento2.3.1, attribute-value

I have upgraded magento version from 2.1.8 EE to magento 2.3.1, after upgrade some attributes values are not showing in admin and frontend, like full short description is showing blank in admin and so not rendering on frontend too.
Checked the values in database, they are present in database.
I have done setup upgrade, di compile, reindex and cache flush .

Please provide a solution.

Comment: Please open attribute set from admin and save again, run caching and indexing command.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya tried this, but not working.